# Java stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

есть такой метод

```
public List<DocType> mapDocType(List<ru.server.model.DocType> docTypes) {
     List<DocType> result = new ArrayList<DocType>();
     for(ru.server.model.DocType docType : docTypes) {
         DocType temp = new DocType();
         temp.setId(docType.getId());
         temp.setDocident(docType.getDocident());
         temp.setDocname(docType.getDocname());
         result.add(temp);
     }
     return result;
}
```

надо переписать его, используя `stream api`, как это сделать правильно?

Comment: мне кажется ваш пример более читабелен, чем когда перепишете на stream api

Comment: может оно и так, но задача стоит именно переписать на stream api

Comment: А в чем принципиальное отличие создаваемого `temp` от `docType`, который в цикле? Если в итоге нужен новый список с новыми объектами, то гляньте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents. Там есть примеры с использованием Stream API. Так же, рекомендую https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-list-to-another. Там довольно много примеров.

Comment: я отредактровал вопрос, указал что docType в цикле из другого пакета

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, какой тут смысл функционалки, но выглядит это примерно так:

```
public List<DocType> mapDocType(List<DocType> docTypes) {
    return docTypes.stream().map((t) -> {
        final DocType temp = new DocType();
        temp.setId(docType.getId());
        temp.setDocident(docType.getDocident());
        temp.setDocname(docType.getDocname());
        return temp;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Но лучше добавьте конструктор в класс `DocType` и передавайте в него `id`, `docident`, `docname`. Тогда все будет проще:

```
public List<DocType> mapDocType(List<DocType> docTypes) {        
    return docTypes.stream()
    .map(t -> new DocType(docType.getId(), docType.getDocident(), docType.getDocname()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: смысл функционалки в том, что Doctype в for и Doctype temp, это разные классы, я не указал это в коде

Comment: Это никак не меняет ответа, как и не наполняет это смыслом!  Создавайте экземпляр нужного вам класса в написанном мной коде и будет Вам счастье.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы было красиво, нужно сделать либо конструктор в `DocType`, либо аналогичный static метод вида:

```
public DocType(ru.server.model.DocType docType){
    this.id = docType.getId();
    this.docident = docType.getDocident();
    this.docname = docType.getDocname();
}
```

либо

```
public static DocType of(ru.server.model.DocType docType){ //of/from/by, как хотите называйте
    DocType temp = new DocType();
    temp.setId(docType.getId());
    temp.setDocident(docType.getDocident());
    temp.setDocname(docType.getDocname());
    return temp;
}
```

и после этого ваш метод преобразится в:

```
public List<DocType> mapDocType(List<ru.server.model.DocType> docTypes) {
    return docTypes.stream()
        .map(DocType::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

или, соответственно

```
public List<DocType> mapDocType(List<ru.server.model.DocType> docTypes) {
    return docTypes.stream()
        .map(DocType::of)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: я не могу править класс DocType

Comment: Ну сделайте это не в `DocType`, а создайте отделный класс, типа `DocTypeFactory` или `DocTypeConverter` или ещё как-нибудь его обзовите, и там запилите `static` метод. Да, будет лишний класс ради того, чтобы упростить метод, но часто так и делается. Пишется немного больше кода, чтобы было удобнее работать с ним в будущем.